# Атомарное перемещение файла. StandartCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE

Tags: java, файлы, io

Кто расскажет подробно, что делает данная опция ? Что означает атомарное перемещение ? Я никак не могу найти её объяснения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объяснение вы можете найти в документации [Files.move](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-). Данная опция означает, что операция по перемещению файла будет произведена [атомарно](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), т.е. операция, либо выполнится целиком, либо не выполнится вовсе.